# System.out.print vs. System.out.println (Last sentence)

Tags: java

I'm new to java and still have a lot of questions.
Can someone explain to me why this:

```
public class Programa02 {
  public static void main(String[] args ) {
       for (int lín = 1; lín <= 3; lín++) {
           for (int k = 0; k < (lín -1); k++) {
              System.out.print(" ");}
           
              System.out.print("\\");
              
           for (int m = 0; m < (6 - 2*lín); m++) {
              System.out.print(" ");}
           
              System.out.print("/");
              
             System.out.println(); }
              
       for (int lí = 1; lí <= 3; lí++) {
           for (int e = 0; e < (3 - lí); e++) {
              System.out.print(" ");}
           
              System.out.print("/");
              
           for (int i = 0; i < (2*lí - 2); i++) {
              System.out.print(" ");}
           
              System.out.println("\\");
}}}
```

works, but with this:

```
System.out.print("\\");
```

at the end, doesn't? (look at the second-to-last line)

BTW: I need it to show this:

```
\    /
 \  /
  \/
  /\
 /  \
/    \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `println` and `print` method is that `println` throws the cursor to the next line after printing the desired result whereas `print` method keeps the cursor on the same line.

[More information](https://www.tutorialslink.com/Code-Snippet/Difference-between-Systemoutprintln()-and-Systemoutprint()/1121#:%7E:text=out.-,print(),cursor%20on%20the%20same%20line.)

Comment: I still don't understand the logic behind it, but thanks.

Comment: Language is not my thing.

Comment: I think I understand it now... but it's not like math science.

Comment: @Lordpascal If you still have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about it and have some examples at the following link:

https://creatingcoder.com/2020/08/07/println-vs-print/

Basically, the print method doesn't move the cursor, whereas the println creates a new line.