# Nested Loops and 2D arrays - Output doesn't form a Table

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, system.out

I am trying to create a program that allows me to create a *grid* using a *2D array* and nested `for` loop.

The ***problem is*** that when I run the program numbers *do not form a table*, they instead are printed out in a vertical column.

I first set up the array with 3 rows, each having arbitrary values. I then use a nested for loop where the first loop is meant to create the rows for which the loop will run, and the second loop is meant to create the columns.

```
package nestedLoops;

public class Trial_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[][] grid = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
                
        };

        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++ ) {
            for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However when I run the above code I get this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Read through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031674/system-out-print-vs-system-out-println-last-sentence

Comment: Are those random values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
    for (int[] ints : grid) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            System.out.print(anInt);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

In the second loop you need to print 'anInt' and to wrap a line you need to add a line break between the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You have to advance the output to the *new line* after printing each *row*.

For that, you need to a `System.out.println();` statement after the *nested loop*.

In the nested loop you need to use `System.out.print();` (not `println`) for printing the numbers of every row. And you also need to add a delimiter (*white space, tabulation, etc.*) between the numbers inside the *row*, or else they will get jumbled like that `12345`.

```
int[][] grid = {{1, 2, 3}, {11, 22, 33}};
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output

```
1   2   3   
11  22  33
```