# How can I print out 1-50 even numbers only, but the it start a new line every multiples of 10. (JAVA)

Tags: java

I'm a newbie, but I'm willing to learn how to code.

I tried using this code:

```
int n = 50;
  int counter = 0;
System.out.print("Even Numbers from 1 to "+n+" are: ");
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   counter++;
   if (counter == 2) {
    System.out.println(i + " "); 
    counter = 0;
```

[%10== 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB5K1.png)

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `println`

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031759/11566161

Comment: but how can I print it out like every line ends with multiples of 10 and starts a new line

Comment: Check if( i%10== 0)... Checks if I is multiple of 10.

Comment: It only prints out: 10 20 30 40 50

Answer (score -1):

to find all even numbers between 1 to 50 and make a new line at multiples of 10 just follow these steps -

- Make one loop which will go 1 to 50
- Check if the number is even by checking the remainder after diving it with 2, if YES print that number.
- Check if the number is a multiple of 10 by checking the remainder after dividing it by 10, if YES make a new line

The code will look something like this -

```
 int i = 1;
    while(i<=50){
        if(i%2 == 0)    System.out.print(i + " ");
        if(i%10 == 0)   System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
```

Output -

```
2 4 6 8 10 
12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 
32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50
```

It's up to you which looping method you want to use for me While loop looks cleaner.
I hope this solves all your queries.

Answer (score -1):

PFB Snippet:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=50;i++){
            if (i%2 == 0) //Check whether number is even 
            {
                System.out.print(i+" ");
                if (i%10 == 0) // Check if it is multiple of 10
                {
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 10 
12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 
32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50
```

`"\n"` is a Escape Sequence which means new line

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck for 2 hours figuring it out

Comment: You could have the iteration variable start at a small even number, say, 2. You could increment it by 2 to never generate an odd number, drop the associated check, call it `even`. Instead of explaining `"\n"`, you could use the (obviously portable) `println()`.

Comment: (What does [*PFB*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PFB) mean?]

Comment: PFB stands for Please Find Below