# How do I print the output in a straight vertical line from for loop

Tags: java, loops

I used a for-loop in my code and my output prints vertically, but what I want is it to print horizontally. For example

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    System.out.println("i is " + (i+1) + " | ");
}
```

For this the output is:

```
i is 1 |
i is 2 |
i is 3 |
and so on...
```

The output I want is:

```
i is 1 | i is 2 | i is 3 | ... and so on
```

Comment: Use `System.out.print`

Comment: Side note: Take a look at [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question, and maybe also remove the repeated sections. You can also read [ask] for more general guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.out.print vs. System.out.println (Last sentence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031674/system-out-print-vs-system-out-println-last-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to System.out.print as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      System.out.print("i is " + (i+1) + " | ");
}
```

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use only `print()` function instead of `println()`
Follow below code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    System.out.print("i is " + (i+1) + " | ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` because `println` prints at new line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("i is " + (i + 1) + " | ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Println prints a new line while print does not